# Is the Lightfoot Halfling's natural stealth penalized by armors that normally confer a disadvantage to stealth?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, armor, stealth, halfling

Some armor types (scale, chain, splint, plate) confer a disadvantage to stealth actions in 5e.  How does this interact with the Naturally Stealthy racial feature of Lightfoot Halflings?  Does it penalize them as it would if the racial feature wasn't present?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not exactly. These are two separate and distinct mechanics.

The first is the [Lightfoot halfling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/14-halfling#LightfootHalfling)'s Naturally Stealthy racial trait. This lets try to hide behind creatures that are larger than them (like their buddies).

The second mechanic is the [armor rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ArmorandShields). This *only* causes disadvantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks.

So a Lightfoot halfling in specific armors can attempt to hide behind their allies, but is at disadvantage on the Stealth check to do so.

Answer (score 12):

The description of the [Lightfoot Halfling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/14-halfling#LightfootHalfling)'s Naturally Stealthy racial trait says (emphasis mine):

> ***Naturally Stealthy.*** You can **attempt** to hide even when you are obscured only by a creature that is at least one size larger than you.

And from the "Equipment" chapter, under ["Armor and Shields"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ArmorandShields) (emphasis mine):

> ***Stealth.*** If the Armor table shows “Disadvantage” in the Stealth column, **the wearer has disadvantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks.**

The two quotes do not contradict each other.

- If you are a Lightfoot halfling, you can attempt to hide behind a larger creature.
- If you are wearing certain types of armor, you get disadvantage on Stealth checks.